# Raspberry Pi 4 with Buster Lite Chromium WebGL not hardware accelerated

Tags: webgl, chromium, hardware-acceleration, mesa

Does anyone know how to get Chromium to be hardware accelerated for WebGL if you start with Buster Lite?

---

**Hardware:**
Raspberry Pi 4 w/ 2GB

**Test1:**
Buster w/ Desktop 2019-09-26
chrome://gpu shows *WebGL: Hardware Accelerated* and three.js renders fine and chromium shows minimal cpu usage.

**Test2:**
Buster Lite 2019-09-26
install:

`$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg x11-xserver-utils xinit openbox chromium-browser`
Then make an auto start that launches `chromium-browser` and run `$ startx`.

chrome://gpu shows *WebGL: software only, hardware acceleration unavailable* and three.js renders very slowly. Chromium also shows > 200% cpu.

---

I think the issue might be related to mesa. In the 'desktop' version, chromium shows that it's using mesa, and the the 'lite' version, it does not. Mesa shows that it's installed on the 'lite' if I query for it in the console and I can run the gears demo on the 'lite' and it renders just fine.

I have the 'desktop' version implemented as a temporary solution, but I would really like to go back to using 'lite' with just chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed `libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libgles2 libgles2-mesa` additionally and according to the `chrome://gpu` page HW acceleratated webgl become available.

**Update:**

I checked it second time, and it seems only `libgles2` is enough to enable webGL HW acceleration

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this next week and see what the results are. Is there some reference source where you obtained this information?

Comment: no exact source I checked which package contains the driver of the GPU (*mesa*), but they are not necessary. I updated the original solution, and it seems only libgles2 is enough. I checked the error log at the bottom of the chrome's gpu info screen and it said that libgles2.so is missing. I checked which package contains it, and installed..that's all.

Comment: That's it. I checked the gpu page and a threee.js demo before and after installing `libgles2` and the install fixed it.

I see the logs at the bottom of the gpu page now also. I didn't know those were there before. Thanks!